# What is a pythonic way of slicing a set?

Tags: python, set

I have some list of data, for example:

```
some_data = [1, 2, 4, 1, 6, 23, 3, 56, 6, 2, 3, 5, 6, 32, 2, 12, 5, 3, 2]
```

and I want to get unique values with fixed length (I don't care which I will get) and I also want it to be a `set`.

I know that I can do `set` from `some_data` then make it `list`, crop it and then make it `set` again.

```
set(list(set(some_data))[:5])  # doesn't look so friendly
```

I understand that I don't have `__getitem__` method in `set` which wouldn't make the whole slice thing possible, but if there is a chance to make it look better?

And I completely understand that `set` is unordered. So it doesn't matter which elements are in final `set`.

Possible options are to use:

- [ordered-set](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/ordered-set)
- using `dict` with `None` values:

  ```
   set(dict(map(lambda x: (x, None), some_data)).keys()[:2])  # not that great
  ```

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: Purpose of getting `set` object with fixed length from big list of data. And then operating with this set(checking if value is in that `set`).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sets are iterable. If you *really* don't care which items from your set are selected, you can use `itertools.islice` to get an iterator that will yield a specified number of items (whichever ones come first in the iteration order). Pass the iterator to the `set` constructor and you've got your subset without using any extra lists:

```
import itertools

some_data = [1, 2, 4, 1, 6, 23, 3, 56, 6, 2, 3, 5, 6, 32, 2, 12, 5, 3, 2]
big_set = set(some_data)
small_set = set(itertools.islice(big_set, 5))
```

While this is what you've asked for, I'm not sure you should really use it. Sets may iterate in a very deterministic order, so if your data often contains many similar values, you may end up selecting a very similar subset every time you do this. This is especially bad when the data consists of integers (as in the example), which hash to themselves. Consecutive integers will very frequently appear in order when iterating a set. With the code above, only `32` is out of order in `big_set` (using Python 3.5), so `small_set` is `{32, 1, 2, 3, 4}`. If you added `0` to the your data, you'd almost always end up with `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}` even if the dataset grew huge, since those values will always fill up the first fives slots in the set's hash table.

To avoid such deterministic sampling, you can use `random.sample` [as suggested by jprockbelly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40736887/1405065).

Comment: Awesome, i was thinking about `islice`, but then i switched to `slice` object which required `__getitem__`, and then forgot about `islice`. Good point!

Answer (score 7):

You could sample the set

```
import random
set(random.sample(my_set, 5))
```

The advantage of this you'll get different numbers each time

Comment: Quite an option, but need to convert it to `set`, i need to run some timeit to understand if it's faster.

Comment: Taking a random sample is not going to be faster than slicing. One of the first things the `random.sample` implementation does is copy it's argument into a list if it was a set (then it samples from the list). But using `sample` may be worth while anyway. It will avoid always getting the same values in your subset (sets may iterate in a non-random order, e.g. sets of consecutive small integers are often in order).

Answer (score 3):

You could try a simple set comprehension:

```
some_data = [1, 2, 4, 1, 6, 23, 3, 56, 6, 2, 3, 5, 6, 32, 2, 12, 5, 3, 2]
n = {x for i, x in enumerate(set(some_data)) if i < 5}
print n
```

Output:

`set([32, 1, 2, 3, 4])`

Answer (score 0):

I went through all the examples above and all of the answers are indeed great. I have one more approach to share in order to slice sets i.e. the use of the * operator. This approach requires us to use variables in order to store the memory address/references of elements. The final output we get after slicing is a list so if we want the final output to be a set we need to typecast the final result into a list or any other datatype we want to. The image of the code cannot be embedded since I do not have 10 points and therefore a link to the image of the code is given. Kindly do have a look and feel free to provide any suggestions regarding the same.
Thanks.

The sample code image

[image: The sample code image]